# why the ping doesn't get a reply?

Tags: dhcp, ping, tcp

I have an embedded board that has the CFE, a minimal loader. I have a host machine - linux FC16, where I am running a dhcpd server. My interface is p3p1. Here are the details of the ifcfg-p3p1.

```
HWADDR=14:D6:4D:1F:F3:F8
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPADDR=10.240.100.100
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=10.240.100.0
GATEWAY=10.240.100.1
PREFIX=24
```

Now, I have the following dhcpd.conf file -

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;

ddns-update-style interim;
allow booting; 
allow bootp;
ignore client-updates;
set vendorclass = option vendor-class-identifier;

subnet 10.240.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option routers 10.240.100.1;
    option subnet-mask      255.255.255.0;
    range  10.240.100.100 10.240.100.254;
    default-lease-time  21600;
    max-lease-time  43200;
    next-server 10.240.100.1;
}
```

The client is not getting the IP address, thus I am first trying to troubleshoot the issue of the connectivity.

I assigned an IP address to my client -

```
setenv -p IPADDRESS 10.240.100.200 NETMASK 255.255.255.0 gw 10.240.100.1
```

Now, when I try to ping my host from the client, I see the following.

At client side -

```
CFE> ping 10.240.100.100
10.240.100.100 (10.240.100.100) is not responding (seq=0)
10.240.100.100 (10.240.100.100): 1 packets sent, 0 received
*** command status = 1
```

At host side -

```
# tcpdump -e -i p3p1 -vvv 
tcpdump: listening on p3p1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
16:20:23.885757 e0:b7:b1:23:60:d0 (oui Unknown) > 14:d6:4d:1f:f3:f8 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: (tos 0x0, ttl 100, id 33, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    0.0.0.0 > 10.240.100.100: ICMP echo request, id 988, seq 0, length 64
```

I see that the mac address is correct here. The client MAC address is  e0:b7:b1:23:60:d0
The host mac address is the following 14:d6:4d:1f:f3:f8.

What could be the issue here? Please give me some pointers here as I am new to networking.

```
# ifconfig
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B8:CA:3A:89:EE:F1  
          inet addr:136.170.195.17  Bcast:136.170.195.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::baca:3aff:fe89:eef1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4362507 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1467982 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5484308631 (5.1 GiB)  TX bytes:115472934 (110.1 MiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:32118 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32118 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6121874 (5.8 MiB)  TX bytes:6121874 (5.8 MiB)

p3p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:D6:4D:1F:F3:F8  
          inet addr:10.240.100.100  Bcast:10.240.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::16d6:4dff:fe1f:f3f8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:209 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:411 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:49526 (48.3 KiB)  TX bytes:60967 (59.5 KiB)
```

I am running dhcpd on the interface p3p1 only.

Comment: On the issue of the ping: Are ping replies allowed on iptables? Can you manually ping back from the DHCP server host to the client?

On the issue of the DHCP: Does the next-server parameter need to be specified? Why is it pointing to your gateway? Is there any file clients need to load from there?

Comment: probably not the problem but, your embedded board static ip is in the dhcp range.

Comment: @chaput - yes, the static ip is in the dhcp range. But, does it matter? I thought ideally, it should be in the range only right?

Comment: @kenkh - What do you mean by iptables here? No, I cannot ping the client from the host. It is not working. The client can speak to server, but server cannot speak to client. I don't about next-server, it is copied and pasted from the tutorials. Ok, I have added a route, whenever I get messages from the ip address ranges - 10.240.100.x , it will be diverted to the ip address - 10.240.100.100. I have done this, since I have two NIC's. One NIC is connected to my office network, and the other one is which I am trying to connect to embedded box.

Comment: @SHREYAS JOSHI - the problem with that is that you'll end up with a duplicate IP or the client will generate an error when he'll try te reply to the dhcp who have exactly the same IP address.

Comment: @chaput - I have even stopped the dhcpd service and have tried pinging the host. I see that the host gets the icmp request, but it's reply is not available to client.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI Sorry, disregard my iptables comment, just realized CFE does not provide that command.

Comment: Any idea, what is the problem?